# Como obtener los últimos 5 registros de una tabla en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy comenzando a estudiar laravel 5.5 y quisiera obtener los últimos 5 registros que se han realizado en un tabla de mi base de datos

he estado revisando y encontre el last() pero solo me permite obtener uno solo y quisiera obtener 5

```
$user= Users::all();


return view('users.index')->with('users', $user->last());
```

Comment: @shaz, perdon no puedo comentar necesito reputación pero te explico por aqui, lo que sucedía era que tenia mal el código, por alguna razón el latest solo me estaba obteniendo los primeros 5 datos de mi base de datos, pero al poner.
lates ('id'), me los ordeno bien un ejemplos latest();
me traia las primeras IDs (1,2,3,4,5) por otra parte
latest ('id);
me trajo las ultimas IDs (36,37,38,39,40) las cuales fueron mis últimos productos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usando el método `latest()` para ordenarlos del más reciente al más antiguo, y luego tomando 5 elementos con `take()`:

```
$users = Users::latest()
     ->take(5)
     ->get();
```

Comment: acabo de ocupar ese codigo (latest) pero me muestra los primeros 5 registros :C necesito lso ultimos function viewaddinsumo() { //declaramos la variable insumos que esta en addInsumo $insumos = \App\insumos::latest() ->take(5) ->get(); return view('Insumos/addInsumo',compact('insumos')); }//

Comment: @MatiasMuñoz ¿a qué te refieres con 5 primeros y 5 últimos? la función `latest()` trae del más reciente al más antiguo.